# Directed acyclic graph / Tree: arrow direction

Tags: tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is it more common to have arrows point to the children or it's parent(s)?

Why would someone prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

It should represent the flow of the information/processing/signal.

So if you have a deep neural net representation it can make sense to have arrows going from children to parents given that the processing start at the bottom of the tree.

But if you have for example a binary search tree, arrows going from parents to children make more sense given that you start at the root of the tree.

Hope that helpful.

Comment: so which is more common?

Comment: I'd say parent to children but it really depend on the type of tree you're working with.